# Determine what attributes were changed in Rails after_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, callback, observer-pattern

I'm setting up an after_save callback in my model observer to send a notification only if the model's *published* attribute was changed from false to true. Since methods such as *changed?* are only useful before the model is saved, the way I'm currently (and unsuccessfully) trying to do so is as follows:

```
def before_save(blog)
  @og_published = blog.published?
end

def after_save(blog)
  if @og_published == false and blog.published? == true
    Notification.send(...)
  end
end
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to handle this, preferably using model observer callbacks (so as not to pollute my controller code)?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

## Rails 5.1+

Use `saved_change_to_published?`:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :send_notification_after_change

  def send_notification_after_change
    Notification.send(…) if (saved_change_to_published? && self.published == true)
  end

end
```

Or if you prefer, `saved_change_to_attribute?(:published)`.

## Rails 3–5.1

> #### Warning
>
> This approach works through Rails 5.1 (but is deprecated in 5.1 and has breaking changes in 5.2). You can read about the change in this [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25337).

In your `after_update` filter on the model you **can** use `_changed?` accessor. So for example:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :send_notification_after_change

  def send_notification_after_change
    Notification.send(...) if (self.published_changed? && self.published == true)
  end

end
```

It just works.

Comment: Forget what I said above - it DOESN'T work in Rails 2.0.5.  So a useful addition to Rails 3.

Comment: Do I need to use `self.published_changed?`, or can I use just `published_changed?`?

Comment: should work without self but I'm using it to explicitly show that I'm working with attributes/methods of self

Comment: I would like to just add that this is very nice, but not very scalable.  In the event you need tens or even hundreds of these I would suggest using an [observer](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/19-use-observer)

Comment: I think after_update is deprecated now? Anyway, I tried this in an after_save hook and that seemed to work fine. (The changes() hash still hasn't been reset yet in an after_save, apparently.)

Comment: This didn't work for me in ActiveRecord 3.2.16. But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9233960/480943) worked for me.

Comment: Same experience as @TylerRick...changed status appears to be reset after the save, these days.

Comment: @AlexEdelstein I think Tyler was saying that it still worked even though it shouldn't. I seem to be in the same boat as you where changed is reset after save. I'm not sure what version of rails this was implemented in. I think Jacek's answer below is useful as is this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: I had to include this line in model.rb file. _include ActiveModel::Dirty_

Comment: In later versions of Rails you can add the condition to the `after_update` call: `after_update :send_notification_after_change, if: -> { published_changed? }`

Comment: There will be some API changes in Rails 5.2. You'll have to do `saved_change_to_published?` or `saved_change_to_published` to fetch the change during the callback

Answer (score 226):

For those who want to know the changes just made in an `after_save` callback:

### Rails 5.1 and greater

```
model.saved_changes
```

### Rails < 5.1

```
model.previous_changes
```

Also see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-previous_changes

Comment: This works perfectly when you don't want to use model callbacks and need a valid save to happen before carrying out further functionality.

Comment: Just to be clear: in my tests (Rails 4), if you are using an `after_save` callback, `self.changed?` is `true` and `self.attribute_name_changed?` is also `true`, but `self.previous_changes` returns an empty hash.

Comment: looks like _previous_changes_ is a Rails 5 function.  You can implement this in Rails 4 by adding an _attr_accessor_ _:previous_change_, fill it in a before_save call and access it again in an after_save.

Comment: @GernotUllrich Also works in Rails 4.2: http://devdocs.io/rails~4.2/activemodel/dirty#method-i-previous_changes

Comment: This is deprecated in Rails 5.1 +. Use `saved_changes` in `after_save` callbacks instead

Comment: also for a single change  ```instance.saved_change_to_published?```

Answer (score 87):

To anyone seeing this later on, as it currently (Aug. 2017) tops google: It is worth mentioning, that this behavior will be altered in **Rails 5.2**, and has deprecation warnings as of Rails 5.1, as [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) changed a bit.

**What do I change?**

If you're using `attribute_changed?` method in the `after_*`-callbacks, you'll see a warning like:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_changed?` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute?` instead. (called from some_callback at /PATH_TO/app/models/user.rb:15)

As it mentions, you could fix this easily by replacing the function with `saved_change_to_attribute?`. So for example, `name_changed?` becomes `saved_change_to_name?`.

Likewise, if you're using the `attribute_change` to get the before-after values, this changes as well and throws the following:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_change` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute` instead. (called from some_callback at /PATH_TO/app/models/user.rb:20)

Again, as it mentions, the method changes name to `saved_change_to_attribute` which returns `["old", "new"]`.
or use `saved_changes`, which returns all the changes, and these can be accessed as `saved_changes['attribute']`.

Comment: Note this helpful response also includes workarounds for the deprecation of `attribute_was` methods: use `saved_change_to_attribute` instead.

Answer (score 52):

In case you can do this on `before_save` instead of `after_save`, you'll be able to use this:

```
self.changed
```

it returns an array of all changed columns in this record.

you can also use:

```
self.changes
```

which returns a hash of columns that changed and before and after results as arrays

Comment: Except that these don't work in an `after_` callback, which is what the question was actually about. @jacek-głodek's answer below is the correct one.

Comment: Updated the answer to make it clear this only applies to `before_save`

Comment: Which Rails version is this? In Rails 4, `self.changed` can be used in `after_save` callbacks.

Comment: Works great! Also to be noted, the result of `self.changed` is an array of strings! (Not symbols!) `["attr_name", "other_attr_name"]`

Answer (score 8):

The "selected" answer didn't work for me. I'm using rails 3.1 with CouchRest::Model (based on Active Model). The `_changed?` methods don't return true for changed attributes in the `after_update` hook, only in the `before_update` hook. I was able to get it to work using the (new?) `around_update` hook:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  around_update :send_notification_after_change

  def send_notification_after_change
    should_send_it = self.published_changed? && self.published == true

    yield

    Notification.send(...) if should_send_it
  end

end
```

Comment: The selected answer also didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks! I'm using ActiveRecord 3.2.16.

Answer (score 7):

you can add a condition to the `after_update` like so:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :send_notification, if: :published_changed?

  ...
end
```

there's no need to add a condition within the `send_notification` method itself.

Answer (score -22):

You just add an accessor who define what you change

```
class Post < AR::Base
  attr_reader :what_changed

  before_filter :what_changed?

  def what_changed?
    @what_changed = changes || []
  end

  after_filter :action_on_changes

  def action_on_changes
    @what_changed.each do |change|
      p change
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a very bad practice, don't even consider it.