# Rails Devise: after_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is there a way to create a `after_confirmation :do_something` ?

The goal is to send an e-mail after the user confirms using Devise `:confirmable`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**For new versions of devise 3.x :**

See a different answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20630036/2832282

**For old versions of devise 2.x :**

**(Original answer)**

but you should be able to put a before_save callback on the user (extra credit for using an observer) and check if confirmed_at was just set by devise. You can do something like:

```
  send_the_email if self.confirmed_at_changed?
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html for more details on checking the change on the field.

Comment: If you want it to send only the first time they confirm, the following should work well. `after_save :send_welcome_email, :if => proc { |l| l.confirmed_at_changed? && l.confirmed_at_was.nil? }`

Comment: For future readers, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20630036/2832282) highlighted that there is now an official callback `after_confirmation` that can be overriden on your user model

Answer (score 90):

I'm using Devise 3.1.2, it has a placeholder method `after_confirmation` which is called after the confirmation finished successfully. We just need to override this method in `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Override Devise::Confirmable#after_confirmation
  def after_confirmation
    # Do something...
  end
end
```

See: Devise 3.5.9 Source Code: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/d293e00ef5f431129108c1cbebe942b32e6ba616/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb

Comment: for some reason I'm getting `undefined method `after_confirmation' for User` ... could this be a devise configuration issue?

Comment: This doesn't work when you want to use the dirty attributes of the model, like `confirmed_at_changed?` or `confirmed_at_was`. Using a traditional `before_save` is the best solution for that, as suggested in the chosen answer's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558463/rails-devise-after-confirmation#comment12853945_4558910).

Comment: method link is [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable:after_confirmation)

Comment: @Anjan you can use `previous_changes` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20657833/2643846).

Comment: Is it possible to make the difference between confirmation and reconfirmation after a user changed his email ?

Comment: This still works in Devise 4.7.3 and Rails 6.1.

Comment: The OP says it's a "placeholder" method (correctly) and "override" (slightly confusingly). By default, this is an empty method (as of Devise 4.8.0). So, you can write whatever in the method and it would not *override* the default setting.

Answer (score 11):

You can override the `confirm!` method:

```
def confirm!
  super
  do_something
end
```

Discussion about the topic is at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/812. They say that there are no callbacks like `after_confirmation :do_something` because that approach would require a lot of different callbacks.

Comment: In Devise 4.2.0 the method was renamed to remove the bang; it's just `confirm` now.

Answer (score 6):

Rails 4:

combining multiple answers above

```
  def first_confirmation?
    previous_changes[:confirmed_at] && previous_changes[:confirmed_at].first.nil?
  end

  def confirm!
    super
    if first_confirmation?
      # do first confirmation stuff
    end
  end
```

Comment: In Devise 4.2.0 the method was renamed to remove the bang; it's just confirm now.

Answer (score 3):

according to the Devise 3.5.9 source code, you can simply define a method on the Devise Resource model, e.g.:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
    def after_confirmation
       do_something
    end
  end
```

See: Devise 3.5.9 Source Code: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/d293e00ef5f431129108c1cbebe942b32e6ba616/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb

Comment: Duplicate of an existing answer just below https://stackoverflow.com/a/20630036/2832282

Comment: I didn't see that other answer, but my answer also contains the source code reference - good encouragement for people to look at the source code.. ;-)

Comment: Then I have merged your source code reference with the other answer

Comment: They're both citing source code, it's not plagiarism

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that callback too, maybe you can try to override the confirmation method and call your callback there.

```
def send_confirmation_instructions(attributes={})
  super(attributes)
  your_method_here
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `confirm!` method on your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  def confirm!
    super
    do_something
  end
end
```

There is a discussion about the topic is https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/812. I tried this way, and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

We're combining answers from @Bernát and @RyanJM:

```
def confirm!
  super
  if confirmed_at_changed? and confirmed_at_was.nil?
    do_stuff
  end
end
```

This seems a bit more performance aware and safe than the two answers separately.