# Rails: Devise: post-confirmation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation-email

I am trying to send an email to the event administrator, after the user confirms.

See: [Rails: Devise: Sending an email after user comfirms registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877475/rails-devise-sending-an-email-after-user-comfirms-registration)

I wrote an EventMailer class as follows:

```
class EventMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  @user = User

  @host_name = "localhost:3000" if Rails.env.development?
  @host_name = "test.com" if Rails.env.test?
  @host_name = "production.com" if Rails.env.production?

 def self.send_email_to_admin
   @@smtp_settings = { #override default smtp settings since I'm using a difference sender
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :domain => @host_name,

     :authentication => "plain",
     :enable_starttls_auto_=> true,
     :user_name => ENV["ORG_FROM"],
     :password => ENV["ORG_FROM_PWD"],
     :to => ADMIN_RECIPIENTS
     #ADMIN_RECIPIENTS is defined elsewhere
   }
   mail(:subject => "Invite request received from " + @user.first.to_s + " " + @user.last.to_s)
 end
end
```

When users register, they receive a registration link. When they click on that link, they get the following error message:

```
undefined method `mail' for EventMailer:Class

app/mailers/event_mailer.rb:20:in `send_email_to_admin'
app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb:11:in `show'
```

Any ideas?

## EDIT:

The solution is to move both the :to and :from inside the mail nethod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `:to => DENT_ADMIN_RECIPIENTS` into the mail method:

```
mail(:to => DENT_ADMIN_RECIPIENTS, :subject => "Invite request received from " + @user.first.to_s + " " + @user.last.to_s)
```

Comment: I still get the same error. The docs say that :to can be in the smtp_settings hassh

Comment: Where are those docs? I didn't see anything [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#label-Configuration+options) about allowing :to in the smtp_settings hash.

Comment: Sorry. not THE docs, but a QA session on StackOverflow. It turns out that the solution is to move both To and From inside the mail method

Comment: Ah I should have noticed that from wasn't defined too. You can also add `default :from => 'no-reply@example.com'` to the top of the class, so you don't have to pass it into every `mail` call you make.

Comment: Isn't it possible to put :to, :subject, etc. in default?

Comment: Yes you can add those to default, but the main reason why you want to add to the default is if you have multiple methods that make a call to `mail()` and those values are all the same. Generally if you are calling `mail()` in different methods, your subject would change for each one, so you wouldn't include it in default.