# Devise reconfirmation hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-confirmable

This question is very similar to [Rails Devise: after_confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558463/rails-devise-after-confirmation) except I'm looking for more specifically a reconfirmation hook

My use case : I need to synchronise a new user email on some third party service (Intercom to be precise).

I have a first implementation using an API where I have put the logic I need there (all tidied up in a service)

However, I often end up doing a lot of maintenance using the console, and the most obvious things that come to mind is to perform

```
user.email = 'newemail@example.com'
user.confirm # or skip_reconfirmation
user.save
```

Using this, I do not fire my resynchronisation logic automatically. Is there a way to force some reconfirmation callback ? overriding `after_confirmation` does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but in the meantime I have monkeypatched my user class with the following (where `xxx` represents some custome methods added on the user class to sync to third party services the new email)

```
class User
  include User::Console if defined?('Rails::Console')
end

module User::Console
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    ## Override Devise confirmable to add warnings

    def confirmation_warning
      puts "WARNING !!".red
      puts "calling `#confirm` or `#skip_reconfirmation!` on the user does not sync to xxx !\n"\
        'Please either use [Name of custom confirmation service], '\
        'or use `user.sync_to_xxx` to propagate changes'.red
    end

    def confirm
      confirmation_warning
      super
    end

    def skip_reconfirmation!
      confirmation_warning
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same use case, where I need to sync a new user email on a third party service.

The way I solved it is a `before_update` filter on the `User` model, and using [`email_changed?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    

  before_update :update_email_in_third_party_service

  private

  def update_email_in_third_party_service
    return unless self.valid? && self.email_changed?

    # We passed our check, update email in the third party service (preferably in a background job)
  end
end
```