# Heya email gem not working in production on Render: NoMethodError: undefined method `concurrent?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the [Heya gem](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya) to send email campaigns and I'm getting a weird `NoMethodError: undefined method 'concurrent?' for nil:NilClass` in production on Render when I run the `rails heya:scheduler` command. I can't reproduce this error in development or when running the command with `-e production` on my local machine.

The full stack trace with logs in :debug mode on Render can be found at the bottom of this post.

Here's my config/initializers/heya.rb:

```
Heya.configure do |config|
  # The name of the model you want to use with Heya.
  config.user_type = "User"

  # The default options to use when processing campaign steps.
  # config.campaigns.default_options = {from: "#{I18n.t('settings.site_name')} <#{I18n.t('settings.newsletter_email')}>"}
  #
  # Campaign priority. When a user is added to multiple campaigns, they are
  # sent in this order. Campaigns are sent in the order that the users were
  # added if no priority is configured.
  config.campaigns.priority = [
    "WelcomeCampaign",
    "EvergreenCampaign"
  ]

end
```

Here are app/campaigns files:

```
class ApplicationCampaign < Heya::Campaigns::Base

  default from: "Please Quote Me <hello@pleasequoteme.com>",
          reply_to: "Please Quote Me <hello@pleasequoteme.com>"
end


class WelcomeCampaign < ApplicationCampaign    
  default wait: 0.minutes,
    layout: "newsletter"

  step :intro, wait: 0.minutes,
               subject: "What to expect from Please Quote Me"

  step :warmup, wait: 1.minute,
               subject: "A gun recognizes another gun"
end


class EvergreenCampaign < ApplicationCampaign
  # segment { |u| u.confirmed_at? && u.email_subscriber? }

  default wait: 10.minutes,
    layout: "newsletter"

  step :week_1, wait: 2.minutes,
    subject: "How Charlie Munger spends the first hour of his day"

  step :week_2, wait: 3.minutes,
    subject: "Week Two Subject"
end
```

Note that I'm adding the users to each campaign in the User model like this:

```
# Add users to the newsletter after they have confirmed their email address by overriding Devise::Confirmable#after_confirmation
  ## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558463/rails-devise-after-confirmation
  def after_confirmation
    WelcomeCampaign.add(self, concurrent: true)
    EvergreenCampaign.add(self, concurrent: true)
    self.update(email_subscriber: true)
  end
```

Also, if I uncomment the `segment` line in the Evergreen campaign I get a no method error on my `email_subscriber?` method. That is an boolean attribute on the User that I can access no problem in the console. My `segment` line appears to be correct based on the Heya docs. When I comment it out it's a similar failure, but on the concurrent? method in the Heya gem itself. You can see this part of the [Heya gem source code here](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya/blob/85d445917b13f89d2ead79be50df5b75d6e84213/lib/heya/campaigns/queries.rb#L17).

Has anyone experienced this issue with Heya? At this point I'm at a loss and filing an issue on Github for the Gem. Am I doing something wrong with how I have Heya set up?

Here's the log file on Render in :debug mode:

```
render@srv-c96sml0nlki0j45uq0sg-7879d459c5-ngv6f:~/project/src$ bin/rails heya:scheduler --trace
** Invoke heya:scheduler (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute heya:scheduler
D, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.242475 #1228] DEBUG -- :   Heya::CampaignMembership Update All (1.7ms)  UPDATE "heya_campaign_memberships" SET "step_gid" = $1 WHERE "heya_campaign_memberships"."campaign_gid" = $2 AND "heya_campaign_memberships"."step_gid" NOT IN ($3, $4)  [["step_gid", "gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/EvergreenCampaign%2Fweek_1"], ["campaign_gid", "gid://heya/EvergreenCampaign/EvergreenCampaign"], ["step_gid", "gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/EvergreenCampaign%2Fweek_1"], ["step_gid", "gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/EvergreenCampaign%2Fweek_2"]]
D, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.244633 #1228] DEBUG -- :   Heya::CampaignMembership Update All (1.1ms)  UPDATE "heya_campaign_memberships" SET "step_gid" = $1 WHERE "heya_campaign_memberships"."campaign_gid" = $2 AND "heya_campaign_memberships"."step_gid" NOT IN ($3, $4)  [["step_gid", "gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/WelcomeCampaign%2Fintro"], ["campaign_gid", "gid://heya/WelcomeCampaign/WelcomeCampaign"], ["step_gid", "gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/WelcomeCampaign%2Fintro"], ["step_gid", "gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/WelcomeCampaign%2Fwarmup"]]
W, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.246714 #1228]  WARN -- : Scoped order is ignored, it's forced to be batch order.
D, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.250234 #1228] DEBUG -- :   Heya::CampaignMembership Load (2.5ms)  WITH "heya_steps" AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/EvergreenCampaign%2Fweek_1', 120), ('gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/EvergreenCampaign%2Fweek_2', 180), ('gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/WelcomeCampaign%2Fintro', 0), ('gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/WelcomeCampaign%2Fwarmup', 60)) AS heya_steps (gid,wait)) SELECT "heya_campaign_memberships".* FROM "heya_campaign_memberships" INNER JOIN "heya_steps" ON "heya_steps".gid = "heya_campaign_memberships".step_gid WHERE ("heya_campaign_memberships".concurrent = TRUE
OR "heya_campaign_memberships"."campaign_gid" IN (
  SELECT
    "active_membership"."campaign_gid"
  FROM
    "heya_campaign_memberships" as "active_membership"
  WHERE
    "active_membership"."concurrent" = FALSE
    AND
    (
      "active_membership".user_type = "heya_campaign_memberships".user_type
      AND
      "active_membership".user_id = "heya_campaign_memberships".user_id
    )
  ORDER BY
    array_position(ARRAY[NULL], "active_membership".campaign_gid::text) ASC,
    "active_membership".created_at ASC
  LIMIT 1
)
) AND (("heya_campaign_memberships".last_sent_at <= (TIMESTAMP '2022-07-05 17:58:13.244738' - make_interval(secs := "heya_steps".wait)))
AND (
  (NULL IS NULL OR NULL IS NULL)
  OR (
    "heya_campaign_memberships".user_type = NULL
    AND
    "heya_campaign_memberships".user_id = NULL
  )
)
) ORDER BY "heya_campaign_memberships"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
D, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.335870 #1228] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 18], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.338893 #1228] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (1.0ms)  BEGIN
D, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.343638 #1228] DEBUG -- :   Heya::CampaignReceipt Exists? (1.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "heya_campaign_receipts" WHERE "heya_campaign_receipts"."user_id" IS NULL AND "heya_campaign_receipts"."step_gid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["step_gid", "gid://heya/Heya::Campaigns::Step/EvergreenCampaign%2Fweek_1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.346390 #1228] DEBUG -- :   Heya::CampaignMembership Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "heya_campaign_memberships".* FROM "heya_campaign_memberships" WHERE "heya_campaign_memberships"."user_id" IS NULL AND "heya_campaign_memberships"."campaign_gid" = $1 ORDER BY "heya_campaign_memberships"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["campaign_gid", "gid://heya/EvergreenCampaign/EvergreenCampaign"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2022-07-05T17:58:13.347669 #1228] DEBUG -- :   TRANSACTION (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `concurrent?' for nil:NilClass
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/gems/heya-e62020064dad/lib/heya/campaigns/queries.rb:17:in `block in <module:Queries>'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/gems/heya-e62020064dad/lib/heya/campaigns/scheduler.rb:42:in `block in process'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:319:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:317:in `within_new_transaction'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:316:in `transaction'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/gems/heya-e62020064dad/lib/heya/campaigns/scheduler.rb:37:in `process'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/gems/heya-e62020064dad/lib/heya/campaigns/scheduler.rb:24:in `block in run'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:71:in `each'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:71:in `block in find_each'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:138:in `block in find_in_batches'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:245:in `block in in_batches'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:229:in `loop'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:229:in `in_batches'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:137:in `find_in_batches'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:70:in `find_each'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/gems/heya-e62020064dad/lib/heya/campaigns/scheduler.rb:21:in `run'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/gems/heya-e62020064dad/lib/tasks/heya_tasks.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block in perform'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:51:in `invoke'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/opt/render/project/.gems/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => heya:scheduler
```

Comment: Without reading the full text and code here, just looking at the heya gem source code you pointed to, we can draw one simple conclusion: the only reason `membership` would be `nil`, is if such a `user` with such a `campaign` does not exist. Therefore the logical question to ask is: do you have the proper `user` and `campaign` set up on your production server?

Comment: Correct. Yesterday I tested this by deleting all my users and then went through the sign up process on Production as a new user to see if this is the problem and I am still getting that error. From what I can tell on the Heya docs, I think I am adding Users to the campaigns correctly with `WelcomeCampaign.add(self, concurrent: true)` and `EvergreenCampaign.add(self, concurrent: true)` in the Devise `after_confirmation` callback.

Comment: The log output shows `user_id` is `NULL` in the queries. Is that normal? Should it be `NULL` or not? Seems suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Joshua, the creator of the Heya gem helped me sort through this over in a [Github issue](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/heya/issues/177#issuecomment-1176980748).

Here's what was causing this error and how I resolved it:

Earlier in the process of setting up Heya I did not have `concurrent: true` on `WelcomeCampaign.add(self, concurrent: true)` and `EvergreenCampaign.add(self, concurrent: true)`, but I kept deleting and re-adding users while I was testing it on Production. So, some of the campaign memberships were created with `WelcomeCampaign.add(self)`, so the campaign memberships for those users were saved as if they were not concurrent campaigns while I was trying to schedule concurrent campaigns.

To fix this I just needed to login to the rails console on production and collect `Heya::CampaignMembership.all` into a variable (e.g. `campaign_memberships`), and then run `destroy_all` (`campaign_memberships.destroy_all`). That removed all of the Heya Campaign Memberships from the production database that were orphans. Then I signed up a new user and all of the campaigns were delivered as expected when I ran `rails heya:scheduler`.